# Select and multiply

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and trying to learn.

I have two tables with (I only show the columns, which we should use)

```
Orderdetails (ordernumber, quantityOrdered, priceEach)
```

and

```
Orders (ordernumber)
```

I want to mutiply quantityOrdered and priceEach for one ordernumber.  So then I get a row that shows the columns orderNumber and Total.

This is what I tried, but i could not figure it out. Should I maybe join?

```
SELECT orderNumber, SUM((quantityOrdered * priceEach)) AS Total 
      GROUP BY orderNumber       <<=Here it says syntax error?
      FROM orderdetails
```

How about join my orders and orderdetails table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment to @Michael Wright' s answer I think you want this:

```
SELECT `ordernumber`, SUM((`quantityOrdered` * `priceEach`)) AS `total` 
    FROM `orderdetails`
    GROUP BY `ordernumber`;
```

That should give you the order number and the sum of all quantityOrdered * priceEach.

If you want a specific ordernumber you'l want to try:

```
SELECT `ordernumber`, SUM((`quantityOrdered` * `priceEach`)) AS `total` 
    FROM `orderdetails`
    WHERE `ordernumber` = 'X'
    GROUP BY `ordernumber`;
```

Comment: I think this will work.  But it keeps saying syntax error. On the GROUP BY line

Comment: How about making an inner join, with the two tables?

Comment: Apologies, the group by was in the wrong place - should be fixed now

Comment: Sure.  If that helped and answered your question please consider marking it as your accepted answer.  You should also upvote answers and other questions on the site that you find useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use:

```
SELECT `ordernumber`, (`quantityOrdered` * `priceEach`) AS `total` FROM `orderdetails`;
```

That will return a column called `total` that has the product of the two columns, as well as the `ordernumber` returned.

Comment: In my orderdetails. There are a lot of ordernumbers with same number. I want to get the total of all my ordernumbers, with the same ordernumber